# what does apple test in IOS applications?

Tags: iphone, ios

I developed an IOS application and I would like to know what apple are testing befour publishing the application.
does anyone know?

thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about Apple's rejection policies. See also: [Why we're not customer support for your favorite company](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company).

Answer (score 5):

Check the [Appstore Review Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/appstore/guidelines.html). Everything in there you need to know!

Answer (score 2):

They are testing to see if you are using any private api, and see if you are respecting the guidelines and test the functionality of the app. If the app does not do what is specified in your description you will get an refuse for publish.

Answer (score 0):

They are testing the application to ensure that it's reliable, perform as expected, and are free of explicit and offensive material.
Did you hear about "I Am Rich" Application? they pulled it because it's useless application.

Answer (score 0):

This will help you to do tricky things.[Link](http://www.opentracker.net/blog/getting-your-app-accepted-apple-app-store)